# Relation between Wigner $D$-matrix and its complex conjugate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, matrix-elements

I have an expression with two Wigner $D$-matrices $$\mathcal{D}^{j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)\mathcal{D}^{*j_2}_{m'_2,m_2}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)$$ and I would like to write the second matrix in terms of $\mathcal{D}^{j_2}_{m'_2,m_2}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)$ so that I can use the expression
$$\mathcal{D}^{j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)\mathcal{D}^{j_2}_{m_2',m_2}(\phi,\theta,-\phi) \\  =\sum_{J,M',M}\langle{j_1,m_1;j_2,m_2|J,M}\rangle \langle{j_1,m'_1;j_2,m'_2|J,M'}\rangle \mathcal{D}^{J}_{M',M}~~.$$

What I attempted, based on what I know, was to use the fact that
$$\mathcal{D}^{j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)=e^{-im'_1\phi}\langle{j_1,m'_1|e^{-iJ_y\theta}|j_1,m_1}\rangle e^{im_1\phi}=e^{-im'_1\phi}d^{j_1}_{m_1',m_1}(\theta)e^{im_1\phi}~.$$

Then, taking the complex conjugate of this and using the reality of the little d-matrix, I get
$$\mathcal{D}^{*j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)=e^{im'_1\phi}d^{j_1}_{m_1',m_1}(\theta)e^{-im_1\phi}.$$
I also know that $$\mathcal{D}^{*j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)=\Big(\mathcal{D}^{j_1}_{m_1,m'_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)\Big)^{-1}=e^{im_1\phi}d^{j_1}_{m_1,m'_1}(-\theta)e^{-im'_1\phi},$$
so that equating the last two I get
$$d^{j_1}_{m_1,m'_1}(-\theta)=e^{2i(m'_1-m_1)\phi}d^{j_1}_{m_1',m_1}(\theta),$$
which then leads to
$$\mathcal{D}^{*j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi)=e^{2i(m'_1-m_1)\phi}\mathcal{D}^{j_1}_{m'_1,m_1}(\phi,\theta,-\phi).$$
Am I correct in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation you need is 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}^{J}_{MM'}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(-1)^{M'-M}
\left(\mathcal{D}^{J}_{M'M}(-\gamma,\beta,-\alpha)\right)^*
\end{align}
which in your particular case gives
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}^{j_2}_{m_2'm_2}(\phi,\beta,-\phi)= (-1)^{m_2-m_2'}
\left(\mathcal{D}^{j_2}_{m_2m'_2}(\phi,\beta,-\phi)\right)^*\, .
\end{align}

This and other such relations between $\mathcal{D}$-functions are given in Sec. 4.4 of

> Varshalovich, D. A., Moskalev, A. N., & Khersonskii, V. K. M. (1988). Quantum theory of angular momentum.

Of course there will be no sum on $M'$ and $M$ in your 
$$
\sum_{J,M',M}\langle{j_1,m_1;j_2,m_2|J,M}\rangle \langle{j_1,m'_1;j_2,m'_2|J,M'}\rangle \mathcal{D}^{J}_{M',M}
$$
since $M'$ and $M$ will be set by the sums $m_1+m_2'=M'$ and $m_1'+m_2=M$.

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies a lot.